# Проблема при подключении через jdbc к ClearDB MySQL (HEROKU)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, heroku

Здравствуйте!

Делаю WebSoket на Java и столкнулся с проблемой связанной с кодировкой utf-8. БД взял с Heroku (ClearDB), так же проверил insert into в самой MySQL. Все работает, а через JDBC нет.

Создал таблицу в MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `heroku_4af59489dcca747`.`message` (
  `idmessage` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idincoming` INT NOT NULL,
  `idoutgoing` INT NOT NULL,
  `content` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `date` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmessage`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Добавил в JDBC вот такой код:

```
private URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbUri.getHost() + dbUri.getPath();
private final String login = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
private final String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
statement = connection.createStatement();
```

В настройках проекта heroku изменил Config Variables

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
mysql://{login}:{pass}@eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com/heroku_4af59489dcca747?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Потом делаю "запрос"

```
try {
statement.execute("insert into message (idincoming,idoutgoing,content,date) values (1,2, 'Привет', '23:11')");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

И где **'Привет'** вносятся символы **'??????'**

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Сами файлы в utf-8?

Comment: Сами файлы в utf-8

Comment: Мм, а сама БД в utf8?

Comment: Да, я писал выше, что делал запрос в БД и все записывалось. Когда начинал записывать через JDBC. он начал записывать "?"

Comment: А вы прям уверены, что "привет" записалось в нужной кодировке? Не может быть такого, что везде utf8, а в таблице в итоге вопросы.

Comment: Как проверить кодировку БД?

Comment: Я пробовал так: `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 'db', default_character_set_name 'charset', DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME 'collation' FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;`

Comment: Спасибо, позже проверю и отпишусь)

Comment: charset = utf8
collation = utf8_general_ci
Ну теперь точная информация про БД.

Comment: А если в `CREATE` добавить `DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci`? Я конечно пальцем в небо тыкаю, но что-то очень странно.

Comment: Вот проверил таблицу и пишет, что collation сейчас стоит utf8_general_ci. Я думаю, что нужно смотреть в JDBC или на сам HEROKU :D